# Is this possibly a basement water drainage system?

Tags: plumbing, water, basement

In our bi-level home we have a sump pump in the attached garage at the north of the house ( *the floor in the garage sits about 3 inches below the grade of the rest of the basement* ).

However, in the finished basement portion we have taken on some water on the south side so I'm looking to do whatever i can do mitigate the problem before i resort to having full on waterproofing done.

Something i haven't addressed yet, since i don't know what it is or where to start, is a 1" PVC pipe that runs ( *seemingly* ) the perimeter of the basement behind the baseboards, but at some point was capped off. The end of this line runs out into the garage and then up and out the exposed part of the cinder block foundation.

My inclination tells me there is/was an old sump at another location in the basement, which was removed at some point. Or, i am thinking some kind of DIY water diversion system, but that wouldn't explain how the pipe leaving the house is higher than inside.

Has anyone come across this before and could shed some insight on what it might be ?

[image: pipe thats been capped off]

[image: where it comes into the garage]

Comment: Where is the water pooling, at the location of the capped pipe?  where does the other pipe that is opened and facing the capped pipe, where does it go?  Why is there a baseboard on the left part of the picture with no wall?  May a picture of the whole end of this room would help us understand what the problem is.  Is the big vertical pipe in the second picture the sump pump?

Comment: [Here is a crappy diagram of the basement.](https://imgur.com/DxRJk4C) The line is capped and the other section of it goes under the stairs, out into the garage then makes a turn and sticks out of the foundation. That baseboard section without a wall is where a door was, for storage under the stairs. I had removed it so the kids could have a little hideout without the door. And yes the vertical pipe is the sump line out.